# Creating New Dataframe from Pairs of Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I cannot seem to create a new `dataframe` using `groupby()` and `.mean()` in python.

I have one dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B'},
 'Col2': {0: 123, 1: 249, 2: 222, 3: 789, 4: 369, 5: 147, 6: 559},
 'Col3': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'A'},
 'Col4': {0: 542, 1: 789, 2: 123, 3: 456, 4: 369, 5: 147, 6: 258}})

  Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
0    A   123    A   542
1    A   249    B   789
2    B   222    B   123
3    A   789    B   456
4    B   369    A   369
5    B   147    B   147
6    B   559    A   258
```

I need a new `dataframe` that collapses `Column1` by unique string, counts the frequency and percentages of the unique strings, and then averages `Column2` by those groups.

I then need to do the same thing with `Column3` and `Column4` in `Dataframe1` and concatenate them below the rows in `Dataframe2`:

```
  NewCol1  ColFreq ColPerc ColumnAvg
        A        3     43%       387
        B        4     57%       432
        A        3     43%       ...
        B        4     57%       ...
```

Can someone help how I can do this while iterating over the list of columns?

Comment: Separate parts can be constructed with `df.groupby("Col1").agg({"Col2": {"ColFreq": "count", "ColPerc": lambda x: 100*len(x) / len(df), "ColumnAvg" : "mean"}})` and then continuing with Col3-Col4 etc but I think a better solution would be somehow normalizing the df so that you wouldn't have column pairs but a group column stating that. With that df, you would group by col1 and that group only once.  I'm not good at that stuff though.

Comment: ayhan, I think you nailed it. You should post it as an answer. I would simply use the same grouping again, only replacing col1,2 with col3,4. I don't see a reason for anything else in addition. If you need the results to be in the same dataframe, you can use df1.append(df2), assuming they have the same column names